# why dojox calendar prevent page scrolling

Tags: scroll, dojo, dojox.calendar

In my page I have a dojox calendar widget.
If with mouse wheel I scroll the page when mouse is on the calendar widget page stop scroll (the scroll only works if calendar is set to monthview). I try to set in columnViewProps `scrollable : false` but not help.

Comment: Provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: i have create a jsfiddle, 
https://jsfiddle.net/efhd/f6b3eqts/5/ 
The scroll of the page is ok only on month view